# Nexus 6 Powered On Strangely

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-6

Earlier today, when trying to power on my Nexus 6, I had a strange thing happen. I normally power on my phone when it is still plugged in to the charger, and I tried doing that today, but after holding in the button for several seconds, the phone did not start to power on as it normally does. I tried unplugging the phone from the charger and powering it on again, but still nothing. When I plugged the phone back in to the charger, the phone began to power on immediately, but not before the [hidden notification light](http://www.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-6-notification-led/) turned green for a second. After the phone finished booting up, I got a low battery warning, as my battery was 8%, even though it was at 75% last night when I plugged it in.

Does anybody have any idea what could have caused this? To make sure that everything was working properly, I turned the phone off and on again without it being plugged in to the charger, and everything seems to be working fine, but I am curious about what happened. I am running the latest version of Android Marshmallow available for the Nexus 6 (build number MMB29Q), and the device is not rooted.

Comment: Is everything working as expected at the moment?

Comment: @Rexford Yes, everything is fine.

Comment: @beeshyams I've only had the phone since August, and this is the first time this has happened. I have since charged the phone to a full 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have confirmed that the battery is just six months old, I am *guessing* that this is a different problem

Nexus and HTC phones seem to have an issue with battery reading showing incorrectly and have a method for *battery reset logic*. This method varies between various models and googling for "Nexus 6 battery reset logic" led me to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/D7er7nMbzHI) method suggested by Claire LP. The problems described in that thread are not the same as yours but if your problem is related to resetting logic, it may help:

> 1. Power off your phone.
> 2. Press and hold the Power and Volume Down buttons. This will put the phone in fastboot.
> 3. Use the Volume buttons to scroll through the menu until you see "Bootloader logs"
> 4. Press and hold the power key for a long time (7+ seconds) until the phone reboots.

Comment: Thank you! If I ever run in to this problem again, I will try this.

Comment: Glad to help :)